# Cómo crear una página web dentro de otra página web

Tags: javascript, html, web

Quiero generar y editar una página web dentro de otra página web, de momento solo para el html. Quiero escribir el código html en un textarea y que la página en html se visualice en un área situada al lado del textarea.
¿Podrías darme alguna pista para poder hacer esto?

Comment: iframe, javascript (jquery) y ficheros temporales

Comment: Hola Mr Baldan. Aqui no se ofrecen pistas ni orientacion. Lo más importante es haberlo intentado. Sobre tu intento nos contextualizas en los problemas concretos que tienes y sobre ello podemos ayudarte. Si no lo has intentado, investiga y prueba. Después has de [edit] la pregunta para añadir la informacion que falta segun [ask] y [mcve]. Un saludo.

Comment: ¿Algún avance con esta pregunta? ¿Mi respuesta solucionó tu problema? Si tienes alguna duda no dudes en preguntar.

Answer (score 3):

Aquí tienes un ejemplo de cómo capturar el evento [`onchange`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onchange) y [`onupkey`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onkeyup) del `<textarea>` para actualizar el área de vista previa cada vez que ésta se actualice o se suelte una tecla tras escribir en ella:

```js
function actualizar(obj) {
  document.getElementById('previo').innerHTML = obj.value;
}
```

```css
.mitad {
  width: 45%;
  height: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
#html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0px;
}
#previo {
  padding: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="mitad">
  <textarea id="html"
    onchange="actualizar(this)"
    onkeyup="actualizar(this)"></textarea>
</div>
<div class="mitad">
  <div id="previo"></div>
</div>
```

Básicamente lo que hace la función es obtener el contenido tecleado en el `<textarea>` e inyectarlo como HTML en el contenido del `<div>`.